# IndexError: string index out of range - Django - Why?

Tags: python, django

I have this simple view function:

```
def location(request,locname,lid):
    try: 
       location = Location.objects.get(id=lid)                
       return render_to_response('location.html',{'location':location},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    except Location.DoesNotExist:     
       return render_to_response('404.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request)) #<-- error line
```

But I am getting `IndexError: string index out of range` only on the production server.

Error line is on the last line.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from your_app.models import Location

def get_location(request, lid):
    location = get_object_or_404(Location, id=lid)
    return render(request, 'location.html', {'location': location})
```

The reason the `DoesNotExist` exception is being thrown is because the id you're looking for doesn't exist in the database being queried as @hellsgate mentioned.

Comment: hey Brandon, thanks, this looks cooler. what is the difference between render_to_response with context_instance and render with request?

Comment: While this is the better way to do it, it doesn't explain why the error is occurring

Comment: render will automatically create the context instance for you.

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually occurring in the first line of your `try:` block

```
location = Location.objects.get(id=lid).
```

This then triggers the `Location.DoesNotExist` exception. The reason for this is that the location id being used in the `.get` doesn't exist in the database location table. Make sure your production database contains the same location data as your development database, including the IDs, and this error will disappear.